# Gmail doesn't show picture which return from Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gmail

Currently, I am doing an task that sends email to user which will contain a picture. The picture is returned from 1 controller.
However, when sending an email, the gmail throws a 404 error even I can see the picture by going to url : Controler/ActionMethod ....
In another hand if sending an email with the src in `<img>` tag hard code which points directly to the picture location in the server, without calling to the controller it works.

For example:
`<img src= "mydomain.com/images/pic.jpg">` => this works

`<img src= "mydomain.com/ImageController/GetImage">` => this goes to controller then gets image which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

becuse GetImage views folder have no images you need to use relative path.
img src= "~/images/pic.jpg" hope it works.